# Filter nested array of objects based on a property value

Tags: javascript, arrays

HI All I am new to JavaScript, I am having nested array of objects my aim is to filter out the object whose role array consists of value like "*_admin" '*' can be any thing.
My data looks like this

```
[
    {
        name:'tom',
        process:'flipkart',
        master:'pharma',
        profiles: [
            {
                level:'begginer',
                language:'hindi',
                role:['flp_admin','flp_teacher']
            }
        ]
    
    
    },
    {
        name:'jeo',
        process:'amazon',
        master:'science',
        profiles: [
            {
                level:'begginer',
                language:'english',
                role:['amz_admin']
            }
        ]
    
    
    },
    {
        name:'jerry',
        process:'email',
        master:'it',
        profiles: [
            {
                level:'begginer',
                language:'urdu',
                role:['eml_teacher']
            }
        ]
    
    }
]
```

could any one please tell me how can I filter the objects

Answer (score 2):

[codepen](https://codepen.io/ken001/pen/jOrMbdm)

```js
const data = [
   {
      name: "tom",
      process: "flipkart",
      master: "pharma",
      profiles: [
         {
            level: "begginer",
            language: "hindi",
            role: ["flp_admin", "flp_teacher"]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      name: "jeo",
      process: "amazon",
      master: "science",
      profiles: [
         {
            level: "begginer",
            language: "english",
            role: ["amz_admin"]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      name: "jerry",
      process: "email",
      master: "it",
      profiles: [
         {
            level: "begginer",
            language: "urdu",
            role: ["eml_teacher"]
         }
      ]
   }
];

const filterData = data.filter(({ profiles }) => {
   return profiles.filter(({ role }) => {
      return role.some(str => str.includes('_admin'))
   }).length
})

console.log(filterData)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use any library (like lodash) this could be one approach:

```
myArray.filter(item => item.profiles.some(p => /_admin/i.test(p.role)))
```

It will return an array with objects for names 'tom' and 'jeo'.

- item.profiles.some(p => /_admin/i.test(p.role)) indicates if there is any profile containing '_admin' for one object (item).
- myArray.filter will return all objects (items) that match with previous .some condition to true.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-liner for you,

```
data.filter(item => item.profiles.some((profile)=> profile.role.some((roleItem) => roleItem.includes('_admin'))))
```

Here `data` is your array.

Let me just break it up for you,

```
data.filter((item) => {
    const itemHasRoleAdmin = item.profiles.some((profile) => {
       const profileHasRoleAdmin = profile.role.some((roleItem) => {
           if(roleItem.includes('_admin')) return true;
           else return false;
       });

       if(profileHasRoleAdmin) return true;
       else return false
    });

    if(itemHasRoleAdmin) return true;
    else return false;
});
```

For more reading on `Array.prototype.some` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and `Array.prototype.filter` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). It's powerful once you wrap your head around how to use it. I'm a big fan of using libraries when they make the code more readable and easier to maintain (e.g. for changed requirements)

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const filter = (data) => objectScan(['[*].profiles[*].role'], {
  filterFn: ({ parents, value, context }) => {
    if (value.some((role) => role.endsWith('_admin'))) {
      context.push(parents[parents.length - 2]);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
})(data, []);

const data = [{ name: 'tom', process: 'flipkart', master: 'pharma', profiles: [{ level: 'begginer', language: 'hindi', role: ['flp_admin', 'flp_teacher'] }] }, { name: 'jeo', process: 'amazon', master: 'science', profiles: [{ level: 'begginer', language: 'english', role: ['amz_admin'] }] }, { name: 'jerry', process: 'email', master: 'it', profiles: [{ level: 'begginer', language: 'urdu', role: ['eml_teacher'] }] }];

console.log(filter(data));
// => [ { name: 'jeo', process: 'amazon', master: 'science', profiles: [ { level: 'begginer', language: 'english', role: [ 'amz_admin' ] } ] }, { name: 'tom', process: 'flipkart', master: 'pharma', profiles: [ { level: 'begginer', language: 'hindi', role: [ 'flp_admin', 'flp_teacher' ] } ] } ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)